# Get distinct column values in a set of datarows - Data Table Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, linq-to-dataset

I have a simple datatable with four columns and some datarows:

```
DataTable results = new DataTable();
results.Columns.Add("Wellbore", typeof(string));
results.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
results.Columns.Add("WB", typeof(string));
results.Columns.Add("factor", typeof(double));
```

I used Linq query to get "list of data rows" when "date=1/1/2017" as:

```
var AllRowsAtPlanningDate = results.AsEnumerable()
   .Where(x => ((x.Field<DateTime>("Date") == PlanningDate))).ToList();
```

I would like to get **"distinct" values** in the "`wellbore`" column in `AllRowsAtPlanningDate` . I just want the `List<string>` and not `list<datarows>` again.

How to do that? I have been checking some examples here but to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var AllRowsAtPlanningDate = results.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date") == PlanningDate) // filter rows by date
         .Select(r => r.Field<string>("Wellbore")) // select only wellbore string value
         .Distinct() // take only unique items
         .ToList();
```

Comment: A very elegant solution.  I removed the where for my needs, but this hit the spot nicely.